# Trying to take the input of a file, evaluate it and ouptut certain info

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
private void evaluateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       Scanner sc = new Scanner("salesrep.txt");       

       while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            try {
            readID = sc.next();
            readFName = sc.next();
            readLName = sc.next();
            readSupplies = Double.parseDouble(sc.next());
            readBooks = Double.parseDouble(sc.next());
            readPaper = Double.parseDouble(sc.next());
            readDistrict = sc.next();
            readMOC = sc.next();           

            total = sum(readSupplies, readBooks, readPaper);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) 
            {
                textArea.setText("Error: ");
            }

            if(total >= 8000)
            {   
                try {
                    PrintWriter stars;
                    stars = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("stars.txt"), true));
                    String newLine = System.lineSeparator();
                    String newRecord = (readID + newLine + readFName + newLine + readLName + newLine + readSupplies + newLine + readBooks + newLine + readPaper + newLine + readDistrict + newLine + readMOC);
                    stars.append(newRecord);
                    stars.flush();
                    stars.close();
                    textArea.append("Sales Representatives Information Successfully Evaluated");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(salesRepresentativeData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    textArea.setText("Error: File not found");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error `NoSuchElement` upon hitting the second variable. Cant figure out why or how to get around it.

Comment: Can we have an example of the data file contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the way you initialize the Scanner object (**sc**). To read a file use:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("salesrep.txt"));
```

The way you are doing it the **Scanner.next()** method will always see only one string which is of course **"salesrep.txt"**. After all, the **Scanner** class does work against supplied Strings as well. You need to tell it that it is a file that you want to read.

On a side note, always remember, names can be [Double-barrelled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name) or [Compound Surnames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Compound_surnames) and both first and last names could contain two or more words (*Otto Von Schnitzel* or *Jacques Le Roux*) and there could be middle name or initial(s) applied as well. You need to consider this when using the [***Scanner.next()***](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method since this method only retrieves the next space delimited token.